# Как закинуть несколько кнопок в массив что бы при нажатий на каждую выполнялась одна функция

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5

```
<button> Hello </button> 
<button> Hello </button> 
<button> Hello </button> 
<button> Hello </button> 
<button> Hello </button>
```

Допустим при нажатий на первую кнопку чтобы он стал красным, если на вторую то он красный и т.д. Сделал примерно так не работает:

```
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); 
for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){ 
   if(buttons.clicked){ 
        this.style.background = 'red'; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const toRed = function() { this.style.background = 'red'; } 
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); 
for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){ 
   buttons[i].onclick = toRed
}
```

```html
<button> Hello </button> 
<button> Hello </button> 
<button> Hello </button> 
<button> Hello </button> 
<button> Hello </button>
```

Comment: Строго говоря у Вас тут не одна функция, а 5 идентичных

Comment: из вопроса не понял, но не проблема :)

Comment: Круто спасибо, помогло. А как теперь при нажатий на кнопку только тот менял бэкграунд на красный, а остальные остались такими какие они есть?

Comment: Добавьте в начало функции сброс всему списку